# ¿Cómo usar forms.py y campos manuales en django?

Tags: python, django, formularios

Tengo un formulario para insertar productos, pero el forms.py es demasiado estricto en cuanto a las clases CSS y los tipos de campo, etc.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Puedo usar forms.py, incluir los campos del modelo, pero luego en la página HTML poner manualmente los campos al estilo: `<input name="producto"> <select name="tipo">`, etc. Y usar la validación sencilla como si hubiese renderizado el formulario con `{{formulario.producto}} {{formulario.tipo}}`, etc?

Usaría manualmente los mismos campos que pondría en el **`form.py`** respetando el name=campo.

### Editado

Este es mi **`forms.py`**

```
class NuevaOferta(ModelForm, model):
class Meta:
    model = Ofertas
    fields =  ['precio_usd', 'provincia', 'municipio','estado', 'color']
```

En el html, por ejemplo, estoy usando un datalist de bootstrap para el campo 'municipio':

```
<input class="form-control" name="municipio" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="municipio">
                            <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                                {% for item in municipios %}
                                    <option value="{{item}}">
                                {%endfor%}
                            </datalist>
```

Es por esto, el *datalist* y otros, que no puedo usar simplemente los widgets de **`forms.py`**.

¿Cómo se puede poner manualmente todos los campos en el html `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc y validar como si fuera el **`forms.py`** en el view?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = NuevaOferta(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
```

Comment: Te invito a que coloques mas información como el código que ya tienes echo, esto para orientar a quien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: @OscarLudick Gracias, ya agregué el código.

Comment: @luisdaniel creo que te puedo ayudar, peor necesito un ejemplo de municipios? Es una FK ? puedes pegar model Oferta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay modelos asi que simule uno llamado Ofertas:

```
class Ofertas(models.Model):
    precio_usd = models.IntegerField()
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.provincia
```

Respodiendo a tu pregunta los formularios de django cubren completamente tus necesidades, pues estos son muy flexibles al momento de ser utilizados, y por lo que puedo ver lo que quieres crear es un select verdad?, si es asi solo es necesario poner las clases que desees en el formulario, ejemplo:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Ofertas

class OfertasForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ofertas
        fields = (
            'precio_usd', 'provincia', 'municipio', 'estado', 'color'
        )
```

Con eso ya tienes creado el formulario listo para ser utilizando ahora al momento de agregar los estilos tienes multiples maneras de hacerlo la manera que yo uso es modificar el metodo init del formulario, ejemplo:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['precio_usd'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
        self.fields['provincia'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
        self.fields['municipio'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-select'
        })
        self.fields['estado'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-check'
        })
        self.fields['color'].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
```

Con eso ya tienes agregados los estilos que deseas, por el ejemplo estoy utilizando bootstrap, ya con eso es mas que suficiente ya solo es crear la vistas.

```
def agregar_ofertas(request):
    template_name = 'ofertas.html'
    form = OfertasForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('tu nombre de url')

    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Y ahora solo el template:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ field.label }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">guardar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudó su respuesta. Ya me decidí a utilizar el forms.py